# Finding an optimal overlay of two point clouds

Tags: computational-geometry, geometric-transform

Imagine I have two sets of points:

```
pointSetPerfect = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 10, 40, 10}, {j, 10, 40, 10}], 1];

pointSetNoise = Table[pointSetPerfect[[i]] + RandomReal[{-2, 2} - 100], {i, 1, Length[pointSetPerfect]}];

r = RotationTransform[47.5 Degree, {0, 2}];
pointSetNoise = r[pointSetNoise];

ListPlot[{pointSetPerfect, pointSetNoise}]
```

Without knowing what I did above to generate `pointSetNoise`, I would like to overlay, as best as I can, a set of points on `pointSetNoise` with the same interpoint spacings as in the point set `pointSetPerfect`, and return these coordinates.  If necessary, I could also click on the image to specify by eye a (very approximate) 1-to-1 mapping between points in either set.

Is there a nice way of doing this in Mathematica v9?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try:

```
f = FindGeometricTransform[pointSetNoise, pointSetPerfect, 
                           "Transformation" -> "Rigid", Method -> "FindFit"]
```

I know it's too short for an answer, but that's it.

The result can be tested like this:

```
ListPlot[{f[[2]][pointSetPerfect], pointSetNoise}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yes, that it certainly is.

Comment: I can't believe this was introduced in version 8 and I'm just now finding out about it.

Comment: @RTaylor Mathematica is huge! :)

Comment: I would make sure the method is not set to "perspective" since that changes the inter point distances. "Affine" should do the trick.

Comment: Actually the zero map is also affine but obviously doesn't preserve distances. What you want is a `"Rigid"` transformation.

Comment: @RahulNarain Edited, thanks